# Img with max-width inside p tag doesn't work

Tags: html, css, image

I have a html code:

```
  <div style="width:100%;word-wrap:break-word;;" align="justify">
    <p style="text-align: justify;" align="justify">  
      <img class="news-image" alt=" Thời trang" 
           src="http://img-hcm.24hstatic.com/upload/3-2012/images/2012-09-13/1347508625-lan-khue1.jpg" 
           style="font-size: medium; font-family: "Times New Roman";max-width:95%;">
   </p>
  </div>
```

I don't know why  `max-width` of `img` dosen't work. If I remove `p` tag, it works.
Is there anyway to use `max_width` inside `p` tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use double `"` quotation mark around your font it breaks the html use singular `'` instead

**change:**

```
<img class="news-image" alt=" Thời trang" 
           src="http://img-hcm.24hstatic.com/upload/3-2012/images/2012-09-13/1347508625-lan-khue1.jpg" 
           style="font-size: medium; font-family: "Times New Roman";max-width:95%;">
```

**TO:**

```
<img class="news-image" alt=" Thời trang" 
           src="http://img-hcm.24hstatic.com/upload/3-2012/images/2012-09-13/1347508625-lan-khue1.jpg" 
           style="font-size: medium; font-family: 'Times New Roman';max-width:95%;">
```